# How to determine if the interface is functional in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

As everybody knows, Java 8 have introduced functional programming to Java developers.

Such interfaces as `Comparator`, `Runnable`, `Callable` and so on are functional.

As follows from definition: ***functional interfaces*** are interfaces that have only a single abstract method.

But for example the same interface `Comparator` have more than one abstract methods:

```
int compare(T o1, T o2);

boolean equals(Object obj); // inherited from Object class

// and a lot of concrete methods more
```

Well, is there any strict rule of *how to determine **if the interface is functional***, so that it can be used as the assignment target for a lambda expression or method reference?

Comment: `boolean equals(Object obj)` is not inherited from Object class. If it was, it wouldn't be abstract. Interface is not a subtype of Object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [JLS §9.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8) (highlighting mine):

> A functional interface is an interface that has just one abstract method (**aside from the methods of Object**)

The rationale is

1. to *use* the interface, you have to instantiate it. Every instantiation necessarily inherits from `Object`, and thus implements these abstract methods anyway.

   > The other method - `boolean equals(Object)` - is an explicit declaration of an abstract method that would otherwise be implicitly declared, and will be automatically implemented by every class that implements the interface.
2. As a functional interface, it is very unlikely that you want to call a method that is defined by `Object`. Thus, these methods do not count when searching for a method to call (because the method of functional interfaces can be called *without* naming that method).

   > This is to allow functional treatment of an interface like `java.util.Comparator<T>` that declares multiple abstract methods of which only one is really "new" - `int compare(T,T)`.

Comment: Having only abstract method excluding the methods of `Object` therefore may it have any number of non-abstract methods?

Comment: Yes, the non-abstract methods are ignored when determining if an interface is functional.